# Database to XML file

Tags: c#, asp.net, xml, c#-4.0

I'm creating a Page in which, while Page_Load.

I'm taking the data from the database and writing it to the XML file.
My problem is I'm having a lot of data in the database so while creating the XML file it is taking a lot of time, which is not working for me.

I need to write the data in 2 to 3 seconds.
Please, I really need help to write the data.

I took the help from :
[What's the best way to write and download xml file in asp.net?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523366/whats-the-best-way-to-write-and-download-xml-file-in-asp-net)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: And how do you expect that to happen if you have lots of data? Purchase faster hardware.

Comment: do it asynchrounsly ?

Comment: Show us how you are writing xml file and how you are reading data from database

Comment: I'm doing it in the exactly same way as it is in the link [What's the best way to write and download xml file in asp.net](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3523366/whats-the-best-way-to-write-and-download-xml-file-in-asp-net)

Comment: so what class and how does it fill it from the db?. Do some profiling to see which part of what you are doing is eating up the time

Comment: That link is about serializing to XML, not about getting data into XML _first_ and _then writing it_.  I don't see the comparison.  It's likely that the former has as much impact as the latter.  Take the advice given...profile it to locate the true bottleneck.

Comment: i checked a link and it is doing paging to handle large amount of data. how to do paging while selecting data from sql server (batching the data)

Comment: Given the pitiful amount of information you are providing all we can do is guess, and probably be wrong. Help us to help you, and stop guessing your self. Optimisation is not a only one right answer question, even with the information.